How to roll up child products/(meaning rows) to main product/(meaning just one row)
I am trying to accomplish something that perhaps is simple but I can't see it. I have several rows of a "child product" that need to roll up into a "main product", just one row. I dont know to group the child rows into the main one and get the correct name.
Example I have this:



Product Code
Product Name
Package Code
RowType
Price
Usage
REvenue
VoucherFaveValue




**GA-ADT
uss-ga-adult
ADUMR-SGR
main**
10
2
20
0


mvCH5
meal voucher
ADUMR-SGR
voucher
0
0
0
5


rvCH5
retail voucher
ADUMR-SGR
voucher
0
0
0
5


**GA-chd
uss-ga-child
CHUMR
main **
7
2
14
0


mvCH5
meal voucher
CHUMR
voucher
0
0
0
5


rvCH5
retailvoucher
CHUMR
voucher
0
0
0
5



I need to get this



Product Code
Product Name
Package Code
RowType
Price
Usage
REvenue
VoucherTotalValue




GA-ADT
uss-ga-adult
ADUMR-SGR
main
10
2
20
10


**GA-chd
uss-ga-child
CHUMR
main **
7
2
14
10




Why not just filter for the main rows? SELECT * FROM Example WHERE RowType Like 'main%'

If there is an actual column in your table named RowType then all you need is a simple query with a where clause to include only rows you are interested in, no rollup needed.

Thanks for your response!, and then how can I sum the two values of the last column into the main one? Thank you in advance

There are plenty more columns that I need to aggregate from the "vouchers" to the main one.

@JonasMetzler There are 2 vouchers of value 5, for each main product so summing up those two vouchers it will give me 10 and I need to put that into that column in the main row

@Tatiana Blanco  we need more examples to find the best solution for you. Do you have non-main rows with values other than zero for Price,Usage, or REvenue?

No need for joins, just use conditional aggregation (where you sometimes replace a value with NULL before aggregating)...
CREATE TABLE Example 
(
    [Product Code]  VARCHAR(512),
    [Product Name]  VARCHAR(512),
    [Package Code]  VARCHAR(512),
    RowType VARCHAR(512),
    Price   INT,
    Usage   INT,
    REvenue INT,
    VoucherFaveValue    INT
);

INSERT INTO Example ([Product Code], [Product Name], [Package Code], RowType, Price, Usage, REvenue, VoucherFaveValue) VALUES
    ('**GA-ADT', 'uss-ga-adult', 'ADUMR-SGR', 'main**', '10', '2', '20', '0'),
    ('mvCH5', 'meal voucher', 'ADUMR-SGR', 'voucher', '0', '0', '0', '5'),
    ('rvCH5', 'retail voucher', 'ADUMR-SGR', 'voucher', '0', '0', '0', '5'),
    ('**GA-chd', 'uss-ga-child', 'CHUMR', 'main **', '7', '2', '14', '0'),
    ('mvCH5', 'meal voucher', 'CHUMR', 'voucher', '0', '0', '0', '5'),
    ('rvCH5', 'retailvoucher', 'CHUMR', 'voucher', '0', '0', '0', '5');

SELECT
  MAX(filtered.[Product Code]), 
  MAX(filtered.[Product Name]),
  [Package Code],
  SUM(Price), 
  SUM(Usage),
  SUM(Revenue),
  SUM(VoucherFaveValue)
FROM
  Example
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT
    [Product Code],
    [Product Name]
  WHERE
    RowType Like 'main%'
)
  AS filtered
GROUP BY
  [Package Code]




(No column name)
(No column name)
Package Code
(No column name)
(No column name)
(No column name)
(No column name)




**GA-ADT
uss-ga-adult
ADUMR-SGR
10
2
20
10


**GA-chd
uss-ga-child
CHUMR
7
2
14
10



fiddle

Oh this looks like it, Thanks! so is outer apply? why the name columns disappearead?

Just add AS [the column name] after the aggregate expressions

Just tried this version with outer apply, runs fast, it is coming the 2 rows, but just the uss-ga-adult for [Product Code] and [Product Name]

@TatianaBlanco Edit the fiddle in my question, to demonstrate what you're experiencing. Then, link the changes here.

If you only need to total the VoucherFaveValue column then this approach might be the most efficient.
CREATE TABLE Example 
(
    [Product Code]  VARCHAR(512),
    [Product Name]  VARCHAR(512),
    [Package Code]  VARCHAR(512),
    RowType VARCHAR(512),
    Price   VARCHAR(512),
    Usage   VARCHAR(512),
    REvenue VARCHAR(512),
    VoucherFaveValue    INT
);

INSERT INTO Example ([Product Code], [Product Name], [Package Code], RowType, Price, [Usage], REvenue, VoucherFaveValue) VALUES
    ('**GA-ADT', 'uss-ga-adult', 'ADUMR-SGR', 'main**', '10', '2', '20', '0'),
    ('mvCH5', 'meal voucher', 'ADUMR-SGR', 'voucher', '0', '0', '0', '5'),
    ('rvCH5', 'retail voucher', 'ADUMR-SGR', 'voucher', '0', '0', '0', '5'),
    ('**GA-chd', 'uss-ga-child', 'CHUMR', 'main **', '7', '2', '14', '0'),
    ('mvCH5', 'meal voucher', 'CHUMR', 'voucher', '0', '0', '0', '5'),
    ('rvCH5', 'retailvoucher', 'CHUMR', 'voucher', '0', '0', '0', '5');

WITH PackageTotal as
(
  SELECT [Package Code], sum(VoucherFaveValue) as VoucherTotalValue FROM  Example GROUP BY [Package Code]
)

SELECT [Product Code], [Product Name], e.[Package Code], RowType, Price, [Usage], REvenue, VoucherTotalValue 
FROM Example e
LEFT JOIN   PackageTotal pt ON pt.[Package Code] = e.[Package Code]
Where e.RowType Like 'main%'

fiddle



Product Code
Product Name
Package Code
RowType
Price
Usage
REvenue
VoucherTotalValue




**GA-ADT
uss-ga-adult
ADUMR-SGR
main**
10
2
20
10


**GA-chd
uss-ga-child
CHUMR
main**
7
2
14
10




The final column is wrong, because this isn't a GROUP BY

@MatBailie Corrected to include VoucherTotalValue

I need to sum up the final column into one, the main product

@Tatiana Blanco  Yes, I think that is the same issue MatBailie was pointing out. I think my updated fixed it. Please confirm.

Self joins are never less expensive than conditional aggregation.  Even when only aggregating a subset of columns.

Hi @BartMcEndree thanks! I think this is what I am looking for, the cte with the left join. Thanks very much all!! Ia m going to try that.

@TatianaBlanco Better avoid JOIN when not necessary, this will be slow and has no advantage.
